# How do I join multiple words in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

As an example, I have 3 fields within my LiveCode application. Field "firstName", field "lastName" and field "both".

I have previously used the following

```
 put field "firstName" into field "both"
 put field "lastName" after field "both"
```

and this does join them, but with no space in-between the names.

Is there alternative methods to do this and include a space between the names?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a && to add a space between the 2 values.

```
 put field "firstName" && field "lastName" into field "both"
```

Btw. your sample code will not work with "and" anyway. You would get the value "false" in the field "both".

Comment: Hi Matthias,
Thanks for spotting the script error. It was taken directly from a tech support question so I've changed it to something more sensible